# Can an Html.ActionLink in an MVC Area render links for the default/root area without specifying it with new { area = "" }

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have run into a situation where I have a great deal of Html.ActionLink calls in the default/root area that don't specify the area such as in the example below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

The problem is that I am now using a new MVC Area that is rendering partial views from the default/root area but the links are not being rendered correctly because the area is not being defined such as it is in the example below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" })
```

The obvious solution is just to go and add the area specification to all of the Html.ActionLink calls but unfortunately there are a large amount of them and it would take a great deal of effort to change them all.

I am in the situation where I must use these links from the default/root area and was wondering if there is a way I can set something to where the Html.ActionLink call would first search the current area but if no matching Controller/View is found that it would search the default/root area? I want to state that I have multiple MVC Areas in the project so the solution needs to be one that works with more than just two areas including the default/root.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default Visual Studio template
2. Add an area called Admin using Visual Studio designer by right clicking on the project
3. Add new Controller in ~/Areas/Admin/Controllers/MeetsController:

```
public class MeetsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Add a corresponding view ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Meets/Index.cshtml

In the layout (~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) add links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Meets", new { area = "Admin" }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Meets", new { area = "" }, null)
```

Run the application.
Rendered HTML for the anchors:

```
<a href="/Admin/Meets">Admin</a>
<a href="/Meets">Admin</a>
```

As expected the first link works whereas the second doesn't.
i hope u got some Idea of this...

Comment: This explains how to do ActionLinks with area specification `new { area = "" }`, but the OP specifically said that they're trying to avoid doing that if possible.